# Render View from string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, render

i need render view from string like this:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public ViewResult ViewList()
    {
        string html = "<div id=\"contentView\">";
        html += Title(null);
        html += GridControls(null);
        html += FilterControls(null);
        html += Grid(null, new Sibi.Seg.User().List(pagina));
        html += "</div>";
        return View(html );
    }

}
```

Then i need render this string on return View() in Controller, see it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return ViewList();
}
```

Comment: While you could render your html using the helper method `Html.Raw()`, it leaves me wondering why you would want to do this?  This is a good example of breaking the separation of responsibilities for what MVC is intended.  Pass back a model containing your data and let the *View* decide how to render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470588%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method of the controller. Your code will look like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewList()
{
    string html = "<div id=\"contentView\">";
    html += Title(null);
    html += GridControls(null);
    html += FilterControls(null);
    html += Grid(null, new Sibi.Seg.User().List(pagina));
    html += "</div>";
    return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

Or you can move the inner code to static classes and call static methods from mvc views, for example:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div id="contentView">
    @(Html.Raw(StaticMethods.Title(null)))
    @(Html.Raw(StaticMethods.GridControls(null)))
    @(Html.Raw(StaticMethods.FilterControls(null)))
    @(Html.Raw(StaticMethods.Grid(null, new Sibi.Seg.User().List(pagina))))
</div>
```

Any of these 2 solutions will lead to the same result.

Comment: Thank you Vorrtex,
When i use this:

    public ActionResult ViewList()
    {
        string html = "<div id=\"contentView\">";
        html += Title(null);
        html += GridControls(null);
        html += FilterControls(null);
        html += Grid(null, new Sibi.Seg.User().List(pagina));
        html += "</div>";
        return Content(html, "text/html");
    }

The return ignores the Master Page (on MVC is _Layout.cshtml) therefore i need Render View.

Comment: @Lucas Argate You can ignore master page by using `Layout = null` as in the second example. Anything that can be done in code can be done in cshtml views too.

Comment: Thank you! I Could not do it, but i created a another solution for this problem, on Shared Folder, i create a View, with name ListView.cshtml and on Controller i returned the list view on method view.